# Hindu Gods/Goddesses In Meditation : Rebirth After Position Duties Fulfilled

Tags: gods, goddess, rebirth

Many people have asked questions on the lifespan of Hindu deities, and has often been answered on here that after their position duties are finished, they are reborn in this universe or another universe.

Hindu Gods/Goddesses are often shown in meditation, like Bholenath meditating on Narayan and Narayan meditating on Bholenath, for example.

If they are doing this, then wouldn’t they be reborn at a really high level ?

Unlike the situation where DevRaj Indra did all kinds of not great stuff then reborn as an ant in that famous story ?

For Devi/Devta types who behave very honorably and never misuse their position, also they are in meditation much of the time, where are they reborn exactly in the next kalp or cycle ?

Would they just stay at the same level approximately in different God/Goddess positions ?

Comment: Could anyone clarify this for me ? 